# flash: change text size according to how big a word is?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I made a flash application that gets the geolocation of a viewer ( city, state) and I'm trying to figure out how I could make the font smaller to fit in the container that I have it in depending on how big the name of the city is.  For example, "Detroit" may fit, but "Los Angeles" may need to be a smaller font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextField.prototype.shrinkToFit = function(mn)  
{  
  var fmt = this.getTextFormat();  
  var pt = fmt.size;  
  /* add an extra few pixels to text width to be sure (there seem to be 
     some inherent margins)*/  
  while(this.textWidth + fmt.leftMargin + fmt.rightMargin + 4 > this._width){  
    fmt.size = --pt;  
    this.setTextFormat(fmt);  
    // break the loop if we've reached a specified minimum font size  
    if(mn != null && pt == mn) {  
       break;  
    }  
  }  
  return pt;  
};
```

Example usage:

```
this.createTextField("tf",10,20,20,200,20);

this.tf.multiline = false;

this.tf.wordWrap = false;

this.tf.setNewTextFormat(new TextFormat("_sans",18));

this.tf.text = "Ten thousand thundering typhoons";

this.tf.shrinkToFit();
```